# Linear Algebra Basis functions and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I have no idea how to solve this and do not even understand the question. Excuse my lack of formatting and assume that that when a number is after a letter like $e_2$ the 
number is subscript. $V_2$ is a linear space with basis $e = (e_1,e_2)$ and the systems of vectors $a=(a_1,a_2)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2)$ where $a_1 = e_1+ 2e_2$, $a_2 = e_1 + 3e_2$, $b_1=-e_1+e_2$,$b_2 = -e_1+ 2e_2$. Let $f$ be a linear transformation on $V_2$.

1) If $f(e)=b$ find the matrix $A$ of $f$ in basis $e$ and $f(v)$ where $v=3e_1-2e_2$.

2) If $f(b)=a$ find the matrix $M$ of $f$ in base $e$

Comment: I thnk the function f is supposed to be applied to the 2x2 matricies of e and b

Comment: Never mind. I haven’t had my coffee yet this morning. It looks like you’re meant to read $f(e)=b$ as $f(e_1)=b_1$ and $f(e_2)=b_2$, and similarly for the second question. Use linearity to compute $f(v)$ and use the fact that the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors to find the matrices.

Comment: If I could get a detailed answer I would appreciate it but I understand if you do not have the time.

Answer (score -1):

**Question 1:**

As amd says in his comment, we are meant to read $f(e) = b$ as $f(e_j) = b_j$ for all indices $j$.  With that in mind, we can compute the matrix of $f$ with respect to $e$ as follows.

To find the first column of the matrix, note that
$$
f(e_1) = b_1 = -e_1 + e_2 = (-1)\cdot e_1 + (1) \cdot e_2.
$$
It follows that $(-1,1)$ is the coordinate vector of $f(e_1)$ relative to $e$, and is thus the first column of our matrix.  In other words, we have
$$
A = \pmatrix{-1&?\\1&?}.
$$
Similarly, find that the second column is $(-1,2)$, so that the matrix is given by
$$
A = \pmatrix{-1&-1\\1&2}.
$$
From there, we could compute $f(v)$ in two ways.  One option is to use the linearity of $f$ as follows:
$$
f(v) = f(3e_1 - 2e_2) = 3f(e_1) - 2f(e_2) = 3b_1 - 2b_2
\\ = 3 (-e_1 + e_2) - 2(-e_1 + 2e_2)
\\ = -3e_1 + 3e_2 + 2e_1 - 4e_2
\\ = -e_1 - e_2
$$
The other option is to compute the transformation matrix that we just computed.  Since $v = 3e_1 - 2e_2$, the coordinate vector of $V$ relative to $e$ is $(3,-2)$.  Thus, the coordinate vector of $f(v)$ is given by
$$
A [v]_e = 
\pmatrix{-1&-1\\1&2} \pmatrix{3\\-2} = \pmatrix{-1\\-1}.
$$
This is the coordinate vector of $f(v)$, which is to say that $f(v) = -e_1 - e_2$, confirming the earlier result.

---

**Question 2:**

This one is a little bit trickier. Remember that to find the matrix of $f$ with respect to $e$, we need to figure out what $f(e_1)$ and $f(e_2)$ are.  We were given this information directly in the last problem, but now we have to get that information using what we know about $f(b_1)$ and $f(b_2)$.

We can use the following procedure:

- Find numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $x_1 b_1 + x_2 b_2 = e_1$.  This is technically a system of equations, but it's easy to solve by "guessing" an answer.
- Note that $f(e_1) = f(x_1b_1 + x_2 b_2) = x_1 f(b_1) + x_2 f(b_2)$.  The vector of coefficients is the coordinate vector of $f(e_1)$ relative to $e$, and is our first column of $M$.
- Do the same thing to find the second column, which is the vector of coefficients of $f(e_2)$.

---

Regarding the matrix-multiplication formula: suppose that $P = [f]_{b \to e}$, i.e. $P$ is the matrix of $f$ relative to the bases $b$ and $e$.  For your problem, we would have
$$
P = \pmatrix{1&1\\2&3}.
$$
Suppose that $B = [I]_{b \to e}$, i.e. $B$ is the change of basis matrix from $b$ to $e$.  For your problem, we would have
$$
B = \pmatrix{-1&-1\\1&2}.
$$
Then the matrix $M$ of $f$ relative to the basis $e$ would be given by
$$
M = [f]_{b \to e}[I]_{b \to e}^{-1} = PB^{-1} = \pmatrix{1&1\\2&3}\pmatrix{-1&-1\\1&2}^{-1} = \pmatrix{-1&0\\-1&1}.
$$

Comment: What about matrix A

Comment: I had them mixed up, see my latest edit

Comment: What about matrix  M then

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Can I get a detailed answer for the second part and can I ask if in general we have f(a) and F is the matrix of the function F and A is the matrix of a system of equations does this equal F times A or A times F ?

Comment: Your question, as you have asked it, doesn't make much sense.  I think you're asking this: "if $F$ is the matrix of $f$ relative to the bases $b$ and $e$ and $A$ is the matrix of coefficients from the system of equations (for the variables $x_1$ and $x_2$), then is $FA$ or $AF$ the matrix of $f$ relative to $e$".  Did I interpret that correctly?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: I don't have the patience to write out a detailed answer for the second problem.  However, if you're just looking for an answer, now you have it. See my latest edit